# Have access to internet but ping 4.2.2.4 results in 100% packet loss

Tags: ping, internet

I am running openSUSE 12.2 on my machine. When I try `ping 4.2.2.4` in my konsole I get 100% packet loss, but I have access to internet. How can I fix this?

I always thought if `ping 4.2.2.4` doesn't work I cannot access internet, apparently I was wrong, anyone can describe this to me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

4.2.2.4 is just a public DNS server (actually probably a cluster) owned and operated by Level 3. It's no different than anything else on the public Internet. There are a multitude of reasons that you might not get a response to an ICMP echo request from it, but still have Internet connectivity.

It's not like the operation of the entire Internet relies on 4.2.2.4.